# Get Week from a date range SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hello can someone tell me how to get the week no according to the given date range (Not week number by year or month) but the date range.

```
Eg : From Date : '6/26/2017' and To Date: '7/23/2017'
```

Results

```
Week 1 - (6/26/2017 - 7/2/2017)
Week 2 - (7/3/2017 - 7/10/2017)
Week 3 - (7/11/2017 - 7/18/2017)
Week 4 - (7/19/2017 - 7/23/2017)
```

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to a TVF (Table-Valued Function)

I'll often use a udf to create dynamic date/time ranges.  It is faster than a recursive CTE and is parameter driven.  You supply the Date/Time range, DatePart, and Increment.

**Example**

```
Select WeekNbr = 'Week '+cast(RetSeq as varchar(10))
      ,WeekBeg = cast(RetVal as date)
      ,WeekEnd = cast(RetVal+6 as date)
 From [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2017-06-26','2017-07-23','WK',1)
```

**Returns**

```
WeekNbr  WeekBeg      WeekEnd
Week 1   2017-06-26   2017-07-02
Week 2   2017-07-03   2017-07-09
Week 3   2017-07-10   2017-07-16
Week 4   2017-07-17   2017-07-23
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Range-Date] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
*/
```

Comment: It works just as I wanted. thank you so much @John :)

Comment: @VidathAdheesha Happy to help